# Getting user location on demand when app is not running, without showing push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, location

I am developing an application (Family Safety) where one family member can request and get current location of other family member **without consent of other family member**  . **Even when the app is not running.** 
this cannot be achieved by push notifications as **Push notifications** won't work when app is not running. I don't want to show user a notification when someone is requesting location. I want it to work no matter app is running or not. Please suggest me any solution to achieve this task.

PS. please don't tell me that I shouldn't get user location like this or my app will be rejected. Because I am developing this application for Family Security company and family members will first read and accept to company's policy.

Comment: 'even when the app is not running' - isn't possible, because it isn't running. your only option is to keep the app running in the background, and hope no-one kills it

Comment: Hi Wain - Wasseem I'm sure meant when "running in background".  Waseem - **edit your title and post** so it says that!  you'll get more answers

Comment: NO. i mean app is not running. I have seen apps Life360 (https://www.life360.com/) which is doing the same stuff. i don't know how are they achieving this

Comment: @WaseemKhan i am working on something similar, do you mind sharing how you have implemented location tracking when app in background/suspended. My use case is to get location details when i send a ping to a user(MQTT), it is working fine when app is in foreground.  I want to use CLLocationManager's requestLocation for single location update, i also want to track location when app is in background but i am hesitant to use startUpdatingLocation as it shows blue bar(asking for whileUsingApp authorization). I have tried few things like silent pushes but nothing worked. Thank you in Advance Sir :)

Comment: Hi. Aditya. You cannot invoke the location manager (from background/suspended) by sending a simple silent push notification to the device. What you can do is to send a VOIP push instead. VOIP push notification is high priority push notification and you can invoke any operation from background e.g. location manager. So start your location manager (for single location update) from your VOIP push handling code and get the location and send it to the server.

Comment: But one thing that I want to tell you in advance. Apple might reject your app if you turn on VOIP notification in the app without some specific usage. VOIP push is intended for VOIP related functionality e.g. Calling functionality like VIBER. so think about this too. In my case I was also using calling feature so they didn't reject my app.

Comment: Thank you @WaseemKhan some how i missed your replies, yes i have seen VOIp pushes but dint wanted to use them as my application is jsut a location based, will give a shot at apple store and see if it works. I will update you once its done...thank a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

First use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` instead of `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` for `CLAuthorizationStatus` to access location when app is quite.

Now use

```
UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];//call you web-api here to update location on server.
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```

This will help.

Comment: you didn't understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting a location of a device without user intervention and that too, when the app is not running, is not possible in iOS.

The only way to get the Device location in iOS when the app is terminated, is to use Significant Location change. SLC will give location update even when the app is not running. It will just wake up the app and give the location update.

But if you want the location of the device on request, the app must be running to receive the request and process it.

Comment: I have seen apps Life360 (life360.com) which request user location even when it is not running and it is working fine. i don't know how are they achieving this –

Comment: Any luck? Did you get solution for your case? Please let me know if you have found one..

Comment: Yes. It wasn't possible with simple push notification. But i used PushKit and sent a voip push to device. Voip push activate application if it is terminated or suspended. Once voip push is received, you can do anything because application is no longer suspended or terminated. But beware that using Voip without having voip functionality will get ur app rejected. I had a voip functionality as well ;)

Comment: Thanks Waseem for the update. Unfortunately, my app doesn't have voip functionality.So i am left with no choice. Any idea how Life360 is doing that? are they using PushKit? just curious!

Comment: I think they are constantly tracking the user in background by using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. Whenever a location is changed this method is triggered. You can save location whenever this method is triggered. Send this location to server whenever a request is received. I tried this but it didn't work so well. I suggest u should give it a try.

Comment: Yes. we can track device location using SLC when the app is in background. We have implemented this long time back.But our original question is how to track location when the app is terminated and that too we need to get the location sending some request using Push Notification. Did Life360 really does this?

Comment: @WaseemKhan can you give some more details? I'm using PushKit too, but it app wakes up only once.